# C++ getSmallest program

Tags: c++, xcode

I keep getting function definition is not allowed where the '{' is after int getSmallest(int numbers[],int SIZE);. I am having trouble figuring out how to fix it and getting this program to compile.. This is what I have as of right now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

// Function prototypes
int getSmallest(int numbers[], int SIZE);

int main()
{
    int count = 0;
    int numbers[SIZE];
    string inFile;

    cout << "Enter input file name:";
    cin >> inFile;
    ifstream file(inFile);

    //Reading from file
    for (count = 0; count < SIZE; count++) {
        cout << SIZE << "numbers read from file." << endl;
        cout << "The smallest value is: " << getSmallest(numbers, SIZE) << endl;
    }
}

int getSmallest(int numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    smallest = numbers[0];
    for (count = 1; count < SIZE; count++) {
        if (numbers[count] < smallest) {
            smallest = numbers[count];
        }
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

Comment: The variables `smallest` and `count` are not known in the function `getSmallest`. The `return` statement is in the `for` loop and you forgot the last `}`.
Also `SIZE` is unknown in the whole program.

Comment: @newprogrammer101 What is SIZE in this declaration  int numbers[SIZE]?

Comment: In `main` `SIZE` looks like a `#define` or `constexpr`, in the declaration of `getSmallest` you use it as a variable. That will not work if `SIZE` is a `#define`, only when `SIZE` is a global `constexpr` variable. Also it would be good to give the exact error line because there is no '{'  directly after 'int getSmallest(int numbers[], int SIZE);' as you write.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your function. Variable `smallest` and `count` are not defined ... you didn't specify type. You defined them in your main, but your function does not know anything about variables in main. Just about variables that you passed (numbers and SIZE). Try it like this:

```
int getSmallest(int numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    int smallest = numbers[0];
    for (int count = 1; count < SIZE; count++) {
        if (numbers[count] < smallest) {
            smallest = numbers[count];
        }
        return smallest;
    }
}
```

*Note the `int` before `smallest` and `count`

I also noticed that this function returns immediately after one loop iteration. You should write that return statement outside for loop

```
int getSmallest(int numbers[], int SIZE)
{
    int smallest = numbers[0];
    for (int count = 1; count < SIZE; count++) {
        if (numbers[count] < smallest) {
            smallest = numbers[count];
        }
    }
    return smallest;
}
```

Also, I don't know if that SIZE is defined anywhere in any header file, but it is not defined in your program.

You are also not reading from file. Maybe this link will help you understand how to read from file: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: thank you. Yes I have the SIZE defined but for some reason after making the changes, I keep getting that function definition error @golobich

Comment: You should show how you changed program, and exact error output